# How to convert date in format of char into timetable format using MatLab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am new to matlab and my goal was to predict using a GARCH Model. I currently understand up to how to model using the econometirc modeler for Garch but I beleive my dates data is not in the correct format to be used for this time series application. Attach is my data and below is the various codes I tried and a portion of my data:

**data**
date            pedestiran

```
'01-Jan-2014'   399
'02-Jan-2014'   603
'03-Jan-2014'   423
'04-Jan-2014'   418
'05-Jan-2014'   320
'06-Jan-2014'   518
```

```
data_table=readtable('collide.csv');
data_timetable=table2timetable(data_table);
TF=istimetable(data_timetable) #TF=logical 1
```

Although the issue with the above code was that it changed my date's year to the below.

```
01/01/14 #before code
01/01/0014 #aftercode
```

My goal was to follow exactly what the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cScPXYYp510) has done but when I try to run

```
time=datetime(collide(;,1),'ConvertFrom','datenum'); 
**#Error using datetime (line 586)
Input data must be one numeric
matrix when converting from a
different date/time representation.**
```

I thought this may have something to do with the fact that my class is chr  for date but I am too much a newbie to matlab so I am unsure what is the next step to take.

Answer (score 0):

See help and examples for `datestr` and `datenum`
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html